# how do I define a recursive return type out of generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

say I have a function that 'enriches' tree nodes with their parents data as well as other data:

```js
static enrichTreeNodes = <T extends { children?: Array<T> }>(
        nodes: T[],
        parent?: T,
        otherEnrichments: any = {}
    ): any[] =>
    nodes.map(node => ({
        ...node,
        parent,
        children: node.children
            ? this.enrichTreeNodes(
                  node.children,
                  {
                      ...node,
                      parent,
                      ...otherEnrichments
                  },
                  otherEnrichments
              )
            : [],
        ...otherEnrichments
    }));
```

what if I wanted to define the return type as an intersection of types T, { parent: ??? }, and say U for the type of otherEnrichements:

```js
static enrichTreeNodes = <T extends { children?: Array<T> }, U>(
        nodes: T[],
        parent?: T,
        otherEnrichments?: U
    ): (T & U & {parent: T & U & {parent: ???})[]
```

^^this would go forever, is there a good way to specify this?

Comment: do you have minimal example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create recursive type like this

```
type Parent<T>={parent:Parent<T>}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwgO2AHgCoD4C8BvMRFYALniVUywF8g)

Comment: smart I didn't even think about that